# I do not understand the definition of a "K-automorphism"

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

I am reading Ian Stewart's Galois Theory and frankly, the following definition is puzzling me

> Let $L:K$ be a field extension, so that $K$ is a subfield of the subfield $L$ of $\mathbb{C}$. A $K$-automorphism of $L$ is an automorphism $\alpha$ of $L$ such that
>
> $$\alpha(k) = k, \forall k \in K$$

What I don't get is...$\alpha(k)=k$ doesn't this mean "I chuck in $k$ into this map (or, a function of a sort) and what I get will be $k$"

So $k$ is being sent to $k$ for all $k$ in $K$ via this mapping...

Isn't this an identity map? So $\alpha(1)=1$, $\alpha(2.1212+2.72i)=2.1212+2.72i$ etc, the elements of $K$, whatever I pick is sent to itself.

I know this is a wrong interpretation but it's the only natural interpretation I can make from the notation. What does a $K$-automorphism on $L$ $actually$ mean?

Comment: A $K$-automorphism of $L$ is a field automorphism which fixes all the elements of $K$. Equivalently, it is a field automorphism on $L$ which restricts to the identity map on $K$. It is unlikely to be the identity on elements in $L\setminus K$.

Comment: I'm sorry, you might be mathematically correct but that doesn't add much information to solving my confusion, that the notation $\alpha(k) =k$ tells me that it is the identity map. Which indeed "fixes" elements of $K$. I am still unsure as to what a $K$-automorphism is and what it does apart from being an identity map of $K$ (which is unique).

Comment: Are you aware that usually in a field extension $L/K$, $L$ consists of $K$ plus additional elements that are not in $K$? What @PVAL tells you is that your statment "whatever I pick is sent to itself" is in general not true.

Comment: I am not familiar with the notation $L/K$(looks like a quotient space), so you mean extension from $K$ to $L$? Then yes, I understand $L$ consists of $K$ itself and extra elements.

Comment: Think of the case where $K=\mathbb{R}$ and $L=\mathbb{C}$ and $\alpha\colon a+ib\mapsto a-ib$ is complex conjugation. This is *the* simplest non-trivial example of a $K$-automorphism that is not the identity, and the first example to have in mind for Galois groups. (And also, yes, $L/K$ is a different — and probably unfortunate, but standard — notation for a field extension $L:K$ or $K\subseteq L$.)

Comment: Hi there, that example still puzzles me because; $k = a+ib$ then clearly $k \neq a-ib$, whereby it violates $\alpha(k)=k=a+ib$...no? If $\alpha(k)=a-ib$ then this means that $k=a+ib$ is sent to some element that is NOT $k$. Doesn't this conflict with the definition?(and thanks for clarifying the definition there)

Comment: $\alpha(k) = \alpha(a + ib) = \alpha(a) + \alpha(ib) = \alpha(a) + \alpha(i)\alpha(b)$ (because $\alpha$ is homomorphism). Now $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$, thus (because $\alpha(a) = a$) you get $\alpha(k) = a + \alpha(i)b = a - ib$. $i \notin \mathbb{R}$, so there is no conflict.

Comment: Maybe this will also help: For example think of $\mathbb{C}$ as a two-dimensional $\mathbb{R}$-vector space. Then $(1, i)$ is an $\mathbb{R}$-base of $\mathbb{C}$ and you can define an automorphism by mapping a base to another base. Send $1$ to $1$ and $i$ to $-i$. Clearly all elements in $\mathbb{R}$ are now mapped to themselves, but your maps is not the identity on whole $\mathbb{C}$

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't understand; why are you allowed to "say for sure " that $\alpha(a)=a$ but $\alpha(i)=-i$? Shouldn't it be $\alpha(i)=i$? It does conflict to the definition in my eyes because $i \neq -i$ and so $\alpha(i)$ MUST be $i$ not $-i$. If this is allowed, then shouldn't the definition be $\alpha(k)= \pm k$???

Comment: Take a close look at your defintion. It just says $\alpha(k) = k$ $\forall k \in \bf{K}$. But as stated before, you normally have much more elements in $L$ than in $K$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$K$ is a different set from $L$. If $k\in L$, we need not have $\alpha(k)=k$ unless $k$ is also in $K$.

Comment: Okay, so $\alpha(k)=k$ ONLY for elements that are in $K$ but not necessarily for elements that are only in $L$? Is that what you're saying??

Comment: @Melba that is correct.

Comment: Ah, okay..that made it clear, thank you

Comment: @Melba no problem.